# How do I make a image fit a container for a slideshow?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have been trying to make a photo fill a div that is the container for a slideshow. I cannot seem to make it happen and I am sure that I am missing some small detail.

I have tried changing the width and height settings for the image as well as the container itself.

CSS

```
img {width: 100%;
    height: 50%;}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.slideshow-container div { 
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;}
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow container">

        <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="images/education.jpg" alt="children doing classwork">
            <div class="text">Education</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="images/family.jpg" alt="a mother father and son at the beach">
            <div class="text">Family</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="images/community.jpg" alt="community standing together">
            <div class="text">Community</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
```

Whenever I change the width to 100%, the entire image grows larger than the size of the screen. What i want is for the image to take up 100% of the width but only about 50% height of the entire screen. I am think maybe the container needs to be resized but I tried that too to no avail. The other thing that happens is if I do not leave the width at 100%, the image stops responding to different screen sizes. That's just something to keep in mind while provide with assistance.

Comment: Check `object-fit` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: `max-height:100%; min-height:100%;` and same for width on the `img`

Answer (score 0):

U can use a object-fit for this.
Your code should look like:

```
.slideshow-container img
{
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Link to docs [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: The image got smaller so I am under the impression that the container is now the issue. Do you have any idea how I can change the height of the container?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 small issues to fix:

first thing is to fit `mySlides` class height to make it 50% of screen.

something like this:

```
.slideshow-container .mySlides img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.slideshow-container .mySlides {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
height: 50vh;
}
```

in img: i used 100% for width and height, and cover fit to make it cover its container.

for mySlides div: i used height of 50vh to make it fit half of screen height.

you can simply change it and make its height static: 
something like: 
`height: 500px;`

Comment: This solution did not work either. I checked it again and cannot find anything in the CSS that could be causing the solutions not to render properly. The solution that you gave offered no changes. Thank you for trying though. it's appreciated.

Comment: It sound strange. I test it with test project and it works fine .. might it be other styles not mentioned in post which making changes not affecting ?

Comment: I added the rest of the CSS code to the post. I probably did miss something. This is only my third website that is going live so I would not be surprised.

Comment: Regardless of the answer... your class in html code shoud be `slideshow-container` not `slideshow container` as your adding `.slideshow-container` class in style.css

Comment: I knew I just needed a second set of eyes. I should've waited a few more hours lol. Thank you